# Criptografia de arquivo de imagem com c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, criptografia

Ola.

Recebo um array de bytes contendo a imagem. Preciso gravar essa imagem em um arquivo criptografado e não o conteúdo criptografado e salvar em diretório. Te como fazer isso diretamente sem ter que salvar a imagem original em diretorio e depois ler essa imagem e gerar o arquivo criptografado ?

Att,

Teles

Comment: Qual criptografia?

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que eu entendi a imagem deve fazer parte de um arquivo com outros dados e este arquivo, por sua vez, será encriptografado. Então, eu não sei bem como é a estrutura do seu arquivo, mas você pode converter o byte array da imagem em uma string Base64, e então inserir essa string no seu arquivo. Para converter o byte array em uma string base64 você pode usar o método: `Convert.ToBase64String()`. Quando você quiser obter o byte array a partir da string em base64, você pode usar o método `Convert.FromBase64String()`.